# Is the square root of the Kullback-Leibler divergence a convex map?

Tags: pr.probability, convexity, it.information-theory, convex-analysis

$\newcommand{\KL}{\operatorname{KL}}$Let $X$ be a Polish metric space and $P(X)$ the space of probability measures on $X$. Given $\mu, \nu\in P(X)$, recall that
$$\KL(\mu\parallel\nu) = \begin{cases}\mathbb E_\mu[\log\tfrac{d\mu}{d\nu}]&\text{if $\mu\ll\nu$;}\\+\infty&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
I know that both $\mu\mapsto \KL(\mu\parallel\nu)$ and $\nu\mapsto \KL(\mu\parallel\nu)$ are convex maps $P(X)\to\mathbb [0,+\infty]$. Are
$$\mu\mapsto \sqrt{\KL(\mu\parallel\nu)}$$
and
$$\nu\mapsto \sqrt{\KL(\mu\parallel\nu)}$$
convex as well?

If this is not true in general, does it exists a measure $\mu\in P(X)$ such that $\nu\mapsto \sqrt{\KL(\mu\parallel\nu)}$ is a convex map $P(X)\to \mathbb [0,+\infty]$? Or a measure $\nu$ such that $\mu\mapsto \sqrt{\KL(\mu\parallel\nu)}$ is convex?

Comment: duplicate of same question asked simultaneously in math stackexchange

Comment: I am finally fully convinced that Civilized people need to send missionaries to that exotic tribe whose members are called Mathematicians, to acquaint them with spelling, etc. MathJax evolved from LaTeX and that evolved from TeX, and TeX was the invention of Donald Knuth. That he designed it as he did for the reasons for which he did is among the things that prove that he is a genius. And he was quite explicit in his book about this that uppermost in his mind was the purpose of making it easy to be fastidious about certain things, among them the reasons for my edits to this question. $\qquad$

Comment: Note that $\mu\|\nu,$ coded as `\mu\|\nu`, looks different from $\mu\parallel\nu,$ coded as `\mu\parallel\nu`. I changed the former to the latter. Daily I see things typed by mathematicians using LaTeX that have convinced me that few among them even suspect that some sober-minded people think that things like this matter, and that there are good and substantial reasons for that. In particular, people who don't notice these differences are affected by them.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Is there a reason to prefer 

\mu\parallel\nu 

to 

\mu\|\nu? To me, actually the latter looks better (even though I accepted your edits).

Comment: @MichaelHardy : BTW, how do you type code in comments?

Comment: @IosifPinelis : The short answer to your first question is that this is similar to a binary operation symbol or a binary relation symbol. To type code, you use the symbol that on the QUERTY keyboard is on the same key as the tilde.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Thank you for your response. Let me try this code: `\mu\|\nu`. As for $\mu$ and $\nu$, they are arguments of a scalar-valued function $\text{KL}$, rather than operands of a binary operation (from $P(X)\times P(X)$ to $P(X)$). So, I think the best would be to use $\text{KL}(\mu,\nu)$, except that for historical reasons people use something like $\text{KL}(\mu\|\nu)$.

Comment: Notice that the amount of space to the left and right of $\text{“}{+}\text{”}$ are different in different contexts, thus: $$ \begin{array}{c} 5+3 \\ \\ 5+ \\ \\ +3 \end{array} $$ That's part of how binary relation symbols work. That's one reason for coding a quotient structure $X/{\sim}$ as `X/{\sim}` rather than as `X/\sim`. With the latter you see $X/\sim$ instead of $X/{\sim},$ so that's wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHardy In general I am fastidious about $\rm\TeX$ but I agree with Iosif Pinelis that in this case, the parallel lines aren't really functioning as a binary relation. Kullback and Leibler originally used a colon rather than parallel lines. This was long before do-it-yourself typesetting, and extra space was *not* inserted around the colons. So for this particular case, I don't think there's clear right or wrong about how much space to insert.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : After all this discussion, since (i) $\mu$ and $\nu$ are, not operands, but the arguments of the explicitly given function $\text{KL}$ and (ii) the spaces in $\mu\parallel\nu$ look excessive to me, I have now replaced the instances of $\mu\parallel\nu$ by $\mu\,\|\,\nu$ (an intermediate version between $\mu\parallel\nu$ and $\mu\|\nu$), now using the code `\,\|\,`. Thank you and Timothy Chow for the editing and discussion.

Comment: @TimothyChow : Let's try it: $\mu:\nu$ is coded as `\mu:\nu` and $\mu{:}\nu$ is coded as `\mu{:}\nu`.  The former clearly has space to the left and right of the colon that does not appear to the left and right of the colon when no objects appear there. And the space surrounding a colon that has objects to its left and right is clearly more than the space that would be there in text mode rather than in math mode: $\text{a:b}$ is coded as `\text{a:b}` and $\text{a}:\text{b}$ as `\text{a}:\text{b}`. $\qquad$

Comment: @TimothyChow : And I wonder whether Kullback and Liebler used a typewriter with the monospaced Courier font. That would put more space around the colon then the thing in text mode above does.

Comment: @IosifPinelis : $\qquad\uparrow\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Thank you for your further comments.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You can view the PDF of their original paper on [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-22/issue-1/On-Information-and-Sufficiency/10.1214/aoms/1177729694.full). It was not typeset in monospace. By comparing with, say, equals signs in the same article, you can readily confirm that the typesetter did not insert extra space around the colons. Iosef Pinelis's compromise looks pretty close to me. By the way, it's "Leibler" not "Liebler." That mistake is far more important than the spacing issue we're talking about.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, if semantic spacing is the main goal (a good one!), then one can distinguish a binary *operation* `\mathbin` from a binary *relation* `\mathrel`.  `\parallel` is a binary *relation*.  (I wonder if you may just have got the words switched, since you referred to $+$ as a binary relation?)  One can get an operation as `\mathbin\Vert` if desired, like $\mu \mathbin\Vert \nu$, and then save it as a macro if desired.  (It seems like there is some question about whether binary-operator spacing is the right thing here, but I just wanted to point out that these are distinct options.)

Comment: @LSpice : You're right: I was inattentive to the distinction between "operation" and "relation", although much of what I said applies to both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand{\KL}{\operatorname{KL}}\newcommand{\p}{\,\|\,}$The maps
$$\mu\mapsto\sqrt{\KL(\mu\p\nu)}$$
and
$$\nu\mapsto\sqrt{\KL(\mu\p\nu)}$$
are not convex in general.

Indeed, let $\mu_p:=p\de_0+(1-p)\de_1$, where $p\in(0,1)$ and $\de_a$ is the Dirac measure supported on $\{a\}$.

Then the second partial derivative with respect to $p$ of $\sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu_p\p\mu_r)}$ at $(p,r)=(1/10,1/11)$ is $-7.17\ldots<0$. So, $\sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu\p\mu_r)}$ is not convex in $\mu$.

Also, the second partial derivative with respect to $r$ of $\sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu_p\p\mu_r)}$ at $(p,r)=(1/10,1/9)$ is $-11.50\ldots<0$. So, $\sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu_p\p\nu)}$ is not convex in $\nu$.

---

You also asked: "If this is not true in general, does it exists a measure $\mu\in P(X)$ such that $\nu\mapsto \sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu\p\nu)}$ is a convex map $P(X)\to \mathbb [0,+\infty]$? Or a measure $\nu$ such that $\mu\mapsto \sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu\p\nu)}$ is convex?"

The answer to each of these two questions is yes, at least when $X=\{0,1\}$, say.

For $p\in(0,1)$, let
\begin{equation}
    F(p):=\sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu_p\p\mu_{1/2})},   
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f(p):=F''(p)4 \mathrm{KL}(\mu_p\p\mu_{1/2})^{3/2}, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f_1(p):=f'(p)(1-p)^2 p^2.
\end{equation}
Then $f_1(1/2)=f'_1(1/2)=f''_1(1/2)=0$ and
\begin{equation}
    f'''_1(p)=\frac{2+4 p(1-p)}{(1-p)^2 p^2}>0.
\end{equation}
It follows that $F''(p)\ge0$, so that $\sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu\p\mu_{1/2})}$ is convex in $\mu$.

For $r\in(0,1)$, let
\begin{equation}
G(r):=\sqrt{\mathrm{KL}(\mu_{1/2}\p\mu_r)},   
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    g(r):=G''(r)4\mathrm{KL}(\mu_{1/2}\p\mu_r)^{3/2}.  
\end{equation}
Then $g(1/2)=g'(1/2)=g''(1/2)=g'''(1/2)=0$ and
\begin{equation}
    g''''(1/2+h)\frac{(1 - 4 h^2)^4}{16}=9- 16 h^4 + 156 h^2  + 64 h^6 \\ 
    >9- 1 + 156 h^2  + 64 h^6>0 
\end{equation}
if $|h|<1/2$.
It follows that $G''(r)\ge0$, so that $\sqrt{\KL(\mu_{1/2}\p\nu)}$ is convex in $\nu$.

---

*Remark 1:* The existence of a probability measure $\nu\in P(X)$ such that $\sqrt{\KL(\mu\p\nu)}$ is convex in $\nu$ holds for any Polish space $X$. Indeed, the case when $X$ is a singleton set is trivial. Otherwise, take any distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$ and let $\nu:=\frac12\,\de_x+\frac12\,\de_y$. Then the condition $\mu\ll\nu$ implies $\mu=p\,\de_x+(1-p)\,\de_y$ for some $p\in[0,1]$, so that here $\sqrt{\KL(\mu\p\nu)}=F(p)$.

*Remark 2:* Let us say that a probability measure $\mu\in P(X)$ is good if $\sqrt{\KL(\mu\p\nu)}$ is convex in $\nu$. Then it is easy to see that the Dirac measure $\de_x$ is good for any $x\in X$. It also follows from above that $\mu:=\frac12\,\de_x+\frac12\,\de_y$ is good if $X=\{x,y\}$ for some $x,y$.

Finally, using reasoning similar to that above, one can show that, in the case when the cardinality of $X$ is $\ge3$, the only good probability measures $\mu\in P(X)$ are the Dirac measures. Since this answer has already grown rather long, I will leave the latter assertion as an exercise to  interested readers.

Now the answer is quite complete.